# Stack overflows from deep recursion in Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming, stack, overflow

After some experience with functional languages, I'm starting to use recursion more in Java - But the language seems to have a relatively shallow call stack of about 1000.

Is there a way to make the call stack bigger? Like can I make functions that are millions of calls deep, like in Erlang?

I'm noticing this more and more when I do Project Euler problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I guess you could use these parameters

> -ss Stacksize to increase the native
> stack size or
>
> -oss Stacksize to increase the Java
> stack size,
>
> The default native stack size is 128k,
> with a minimum value of 1000 bytes.
> The default java stack size is 400k,
> with a minimum value of 1000 bytes.

http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs61/faq/java.html#251197

EDIT:

After reading the first comment (Chuck´s), as well as re reading the question and reading another answers, i´d like to clarify that i interpreted the question as just "increase stack size". I didn´t intend to say that you can have infinite stacks, such as in functional programming (a programming paradigm which i´ve only scratched its surface).

Comment: This can give you more levels, but the stack size is still limited. You won't be able to recurse infinitely like in a functional language with tall-call elimination.

Answer (score 90):

Increasing the stack size will only serve as a temporary bandage. As others have pointed out, what you really want is tail call elimination, and Java does not have this for various reasons. However, you can cheat if you want.

Red pill in hand? OK, this way please.

There are ways in which you can exchange stack for heap. For example, instead of making a recursive call within a function, have it return a **lazy datastructure** that makes the call when evaluated. You can then unwind the "stack" with Java's for-construct. I'll demonstrate with an example. Consider this Haskell code:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (x:xs) = (f x) : map f xs
```

Note that this function never evaluates the tail of the list. So the function doesn't actually need to make a recursive call. In Haskell, it actually returns a *thunk* for the tail, which is called if it's ever needed. We can do the same thing in Java (this uses classes from [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org)):

```
public <B> Stream<B> map(final F<A, B> f, final Stream<A> as)
  {return as.isEmpty()
     ? nil()
     : cons(f.f(as.head()), new P1<Stream<A>>()
         {public Stream<A> _1()
           {return map(f, as.tail);}});}
```

Note that `Stream<A>` consists of a value of type `A` and a value of type `P1` which is like a thunk that returns the rest of the stream when _1() is called. While it certainly looks like recursion, the recursive call to map is not made, but becomes part of the Stream datastructure.

This can then be unwound with a regular for-construct.

```
for (Stream<B> b = bs; b.isNotEmpty(); b = b.tail()._1())
  {System.out.println(b.head());}
```

Here's another example, since you were talking about Project Euler. This program uses mutually recursive functions and does not blow the stack, even for millions of calls:

```
import fj.*; import fj.data.Natural;
import static fj.data.Enumerator.naturalEnumerator;
import static fj.data.Natural.*; import static fj.pre.Ord.naturalOrd;
import fj.data.Stream; import fj.data.vector.V2;
import static fj.data.Stream.*; import static fj.pre.Show.*;

public class Primes
  {public static Stream<Natural> primes()
    {return cons(natural(2).some(), new P1<Stream<Natural>>()
       {public Stream<Natural> _1()
         {return forever(naturalEnumerator, natural(3).some(), 2)
                 .filter(new F<Natural, Boolean>()
                   {public Boolean f(final Natural n)
                      {return primeFactors(n).length() == 1;}});}});}

   public static Stream<Natural> primeFactors(final Natural n)
     {return factor(n, natural(2).some(), primes().tail());}

   public static Stream<Natural> factor(final Natural n, final Natural p,
                                        final P1<Stream<Natural>> ps)
     {for (Stream<Natural> ns = cons(p, ps); true; ns = ns.tail()._1())
          {final Natural h = ns.head();
           final P1<Stream<Natural>> t = ns.tail();
           if (naturalOrd.isGreaterThan(h.multiply(h), n))
              return single(n);
           else {final V2<Natural> dm = n.divmod(h);
                 if (naturalOrd.eq(dm._2(), ZERO))
                    return cons(h, new P1<Stream<Natural>>()
                      {public Stream<Natural> _1()
                        {return factor(dm._1(), h, t);}});}}}

   public static void main(final String[] a)
     {streamShow(naturalShow).println(primes().takeWhile
       (naturalOrd.isLessThan(natural(Long.valueOf(a[0])).some())));}}
```

Another thing you can do to exchange stack for heap is to use **multiple threads**. The idea is that instead of making a recursive call, *you create a thunk that makes the call, hand this thunk off to a new thread and let the current thread exit the function.* This is the idea behind things like Stackless Python.

The following is an example of that in Java. Apologies that it's a bit opaque to look at without the `import static` clauses:

```
public static <A, B> Promise<B> foldRight(final Strategy<Unit> s,
                                          final F<A, F<B, B>> f,
                                          final B b,
                                          final List<A> as)
  {return as.isEmpty()
     ? promise(s, P.p(b))
     : liftM2(f).f
         (promise(s, P.p(as.head()))).f
         (join(s, new P1<Promise<B>>>()
            {public Promise<B> _1()
              {return foldRight(s, f, b, as.tail());}}));}
```

`Strategy<Unit> s` is backed by a thread pool, and the `promise` function hands a thunk to the thread pool, returning a `Promise`, which is very much like `java.util.concurrent.Future`, only better. [See here.](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/a-better-future/) The point is that the method above *folds a right-recursive datastructure to the right in O(1) stack*, which ordinarily requires tail-call elimination. So we've effectively achived TCE, in exchange for some complexity. You would call this function as follows:

```
Strategy<Unit> s = Strategy.simpleThreadStrategy();
int x = foldRight(s, Integers.add, List.nil(), range(1, 10000)).claim();
System.out.println(x); // 49995000
```

Note that this latter technique works perfectly well for nonlinear recursion. That is, it will run in constant stack even algorithms that don't have tail calls.

Another thing you can do is employ a technique called **trampolining**. A trampoline is a computation, reified as a data structure, that can be stepped through. The [Functional Java library](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/Trampoline.java) includes a [`Trampoline`](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/Trampoline.java) data type that I wrote, which effectively lets you turn any function call into a tail call. As an example [here is a trampolined `foldRightC` that folds to the right in constant stack:](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/List.java#L635)

```
public final <B> Trampoline<B> foldRightC(final F2<A, B, B> f, final B b)
  {return Trampoline.suspend(new P1<Trampoline<B>>()
    {public Trampoline<B> _1()
      {return isEmpty()
         ? Trampoline.pure(b)
         : tail().foldRightC(f, b).map(f.f(head()));}});}
```

It's the same principle as using multiple threads, except that instead of invoking each step in its own thread, we construct each step on the heap, very much like using a `Stream`, and then we run all the steps in a single loop with `Trampoline.run`.

Comment: That is some of the craziest Java code I've seen written, +1 for the very detailed explanation.

Comment: Are there any benchmarks for performance using these techniques?

Comment: @Nik: The greatest performance improvement is going from not working (StackOverflowError) to working.

Comment: Just trying to understand benefit of recursion over iteration using the above methods. (Other than being really cool. :))

Comment: The tinyurl link is broken. Does anyone know where it lead to?

Answer (score 24):

It's up to the JVM whether or not to use tail recursion - I don't know offhand whether any of them do, but you shouldn't rely on it. In particular, changing the stack size would *very* rarely be the right thing to do, unless you had some hard limit of how many levels of recursion you would actually use, and you knew exactly how much stack space each would take up. Very fragile.

Basically, you shouldn't use unbounded recursion in a language which isn't build for it. You'll have to use iteration instead, I'm afraid. And yes, that can be a slight pain sometimes :(

Comment: I know Sun's JVM does not optimize tail recursion, and I don't think any of the other major JVMs do either. There might be an experimental one or two that do.

Comment: I **think** IBM's might. I heard that second- or third-hand, though, so don't quote me on that ;P

Comment: Work on tail call optimization is underway, but its not currently supported in Java because it breaks some expectations about how the stack looks, which are important for Java's security model (and less important things, like stack traces). http://blogs.sun.com/jrose/entry/tail_calls_in_the_vm

Comment: @Jon: a complaint JVM is *not* *allowed* to optimize general tail calls because it violates the security model.  Tail recursion should be permissible as a special case, but I'd be surprised if many JVMs supported it, since it's harder to support the special case than the general one.

Comment: Norman: While trying to find out whether any JVMs did this, I read that claim too - but also that some IBM researchers had managed to do it. It's possible that they'd only supported the special case, mind you.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I shouldn't use Java to walk a tree? Or should I implement my stack in the heap? Maybe then I should use the language design pattern.

Comment: @Dog: You should implement your stack in the heap, and not use unbounded recursion.

Comment: I believe the Avian VM can do tail calls, though I don't know any details

Answer (score 9):

[If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx).

Now, while you can probably find a way to increase the default stack in java, let me just add my 2 cents in that you really need to find another way to do what you want to do, instead of relying on an increased stack.

Since the java spec doesn't make it mandatory for JVM's to implement tail-recursion optimization techniques, the only way to get around the problem is to reduce the stack pressure, either by reducing the number of local variables/parameters that needs to be kept track of, or ideally by just reducing the level of recursion significantly, or just rewrite without recursion at all.

Comment: Why is checking to see if a language supports tail-call elimination "wrong"?

Comment: It isn't, but Java doesn't mandate it, so you can't rely on it. The situation would be different if Java mandated tail-recursion optimization, then I would just say that you should try to restructure the recursion to always take advantage of it. Since it doesn't, I didn't.

Comment: Care to point out how it is wrong? Note that I said that it was my 2 cents, in other words, an opinion. You're free to disagree, but to say it is wrong, then you really have to give more details as to why you think it is wrong. Other comments here have given more information about why JVM's doesn't implement tail-call recursion.

Comment: Your answer is far too opinion based and has, in my opinion, far too many up-votes considering it doesn't actually give any informative points to the discussion.

Answer (score 8):

Most functional languages have support for tail recursion. However, most Java compilers don't support this. Instead it make another function call. This means that there will always be an upper bound on number of recursive calls you can make (as you'll eventually run out of stack space).

With tail recursion you reuse the stack frame of the function that is recursing, so you don't have the same constraints on the stack.

Answer (score 7):

You can set this on the commandline:

java -Xss8M class

Answer (score 7):

Clojure, which runs on the Java VM, would very much like to implement tail call optimization, but it can't due to a restriction in the JVM bytecode (I don't know the details).  As a consequence, it can only help itself with a special "recur" form, which implements a few basic features you'd expect from proper tail recursion.

Anyway, this means that the JVM currently *cannot* support tail call optimization.  I would strongly suggest not to use recursion as a general looping construct on the JVM.  My personal view is that Java is not a sufficiently high level language.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <A, B> Promise<B> foldRight(final Strategy<Unit> s,
                                          final F<A, F<B, B>> f,
                                          final B b,
                                          final List<A> as)
{
    return as.isEmpty() ? promise(s, P.p(b))
    : liftM2(f).f(promise(s, P.p(as.head())))
      .f(join(s, new F<List<A>, P1<Promise<B>>>()
        {
             public Promise<B> f(List<A> l)
             {
                 return foldRight(s, f, b, l);
             }
         }.f(as.tail())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and ended up **rewriting the recursion into a for-loop** and that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

in eclipse if you are using, set **-xss2m** as vm arguments.

or

-xss2m directly  on commandline.

```
java -xss2m classname
```