# afterTextChanged crashes

Tags: android, textwatcher

I tried to implement the Textwatcher interface, I am trying to change the text in `afterTextChanged()`, but it crashes. Why does this crash? :

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Editable myText;

            if(s.toString().contains("hi")){
                myText = s.append(" ho");
                myEdit.setText(myText);

            }
        }
```

Logcat

```
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1720)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:164)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.access$000(DynamicLayout.java:35)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:621)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(DynamicLayout.java:631)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:247)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.textfields.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7108)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8805)
01-27 01:23:18.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
```

Comment: what is myEdit? Where do you define it? What is the error?

Comment: @yygyt I get a StackOverflow. myEdit is my EditText, everything is defined right.

Comment: Can you put up a log from crash?

Comment: @user1944449 `StackOverFlowException`?

Comment: @Glenn StackOverflowError yap

Comment: @VendettaDroid I edited my question and pasted in the logcat

Comment: yes I saw it. May be look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror

Comment: @user1944449 did you set `TextWatcher` to `myEdit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call [removeTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#removeTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) on your `EditText` before you set its text, and add your listener back after changing the text. Otherwise `afterTextChanged()` will keep getting called, like you've noticed.

Comment: I do not set the edittext text. Just calling a method on `afterTextChanged` and pass the text to that method.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this:-

**This also for changing alternate editText value after change.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements TextWatcher{

   EditText editText1, editText2;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

       editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
       editText2.addTextChangedListener(this);

      }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
           int 
           count, int after) {

    }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
           before, int count) {

   }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      if (getCurrentFocus() == editText1) {
         // is only executed if the EditText was directly 
            changed by the user.
          Log.e("check","getCurrentFocus() == editText1");

          editText2.removeTextChangedListener(this);

          editText2.setText(String.valueOf(s));

          editText2.addTextChangedListener(this);

       //            editText1.clearFocus();
      }

      if (getCurrentFocus() == editText2) {
          // is only executed if the EditText was directly 
             changed by the user
          Log.e("check","getCurrentFocus() == editText2");

          editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this);

          editText1.setText(String.valueOf(s));

          editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);

        //            editText2.clearFocus();
        }


   }

}
```