# Gson crashes when writing object

Tags: android, gson

I've used Gson many times and this is the first time I face such a problem, once  I want to write the object to the shared preferences, the app crashes without any exception in the logcat can you please help me

I'm saving the object like this (like I always do):

```
mShared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.this);
edit = mShared.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(currentTeam);
edit.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.current_team), json).apply();
```

here are the classes:

**GameType.java**

```
public class GameType implements Parcelable{

    private int id;
    private String lookupCode, name, namePS, icon;
    private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    public GameType(){

    }

    public List<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }

    public void setTeams(List<Team> teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLookupCode() {
        return lookupCode;
    }

    public void setLookupCode(String lookupCode) {
        this.lookupCode = lookupCode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNamePS() {
        return namePS;
    }

    public void setNamePS(String namePS) {
        this.namePS = namePS;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(id);

        dest.writeString(lookupCode);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(namePS);
        dest.writeString(icon);

        dest.writeList(teams);
    }

    // "De-parcel object
    private GameType(Parcel in) {

        id = in.readInt();

        lookupCode=in.readString();
        name=in.readString();
        namePS = in.readString();
        icon = in.readString();

        in.readList(teams,getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public GameType createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new GameType(in);
        }

        public GameType[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GameType[size];
        }
    };

}
```

**Team.java**

```
public class Team implements Parcelable{

    private int id;
    private String namePs, logo , nameEn, textColor, firstColor, secondColor, thirdColor;
    private GameType game;

    public Team(){

        id = -1;
        namePs = "";
        logo = "";
        nameEn = "";
        textColor = "";
        firstColor = "";
        secondColor = "";
        thirdColor = "";
        game = new GameType();
    }

    public Team(int id, String logo,  String namePs, String nameEn, String textColor, String firstColor, String secondColor, String thirdColor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.namePs = namePs;
        this.nameEn = nameEn;
        this.logo = logo;

        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.firstColor = firstColor;
        this.secondColor = secondColor;
        this.thirdColor = thirdColor;
    }

    public void setGame(GameType game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public GameType getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNamePs() {
        return namePs;
    }

    public void setNamePs(String nameFa) {
        this.namePs = nameFa;
    }

    public String getNameEn() {
        return nameEn;
    }

    public void setNameEn(String nameEn) {
        this.nameEn = nameEn;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public void setTextColor(String textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    public String getFirstColor() {
        return firstColor;
    }

    public void setFirstColor(String firstColor) {
        this.firstColor = firstColor;
    }

    public String getSecondColor() {
        return secondColor;
    }

    public void setSecondColor(String secondColor) {
        this.secondColor = secondColor;
    }

    public String getThirdColor() {
        return thirdColor;
    }

    public void setThirdColor(String thirdColor) {
        this.thirdColor = thirdColor;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(id);

        dest.writeString(namePs);
        dest.writeString(logo);
        dest.writeString(nameEn);
        dest.writeString(textColor);
        dest.writeString(firstColor);
        dest.writeString(secondColor);
        dest.writeString(thirdColor);
        dest.writeParcelable(game, flags);
    }

    // "De-parcel object
    private Team(Parcel in) {

        id = in.readInt();

        namePs = in.readString();
        logo = in.readString();
        nameEn = in.readString();
        textColor = in.readString();
        firstColor = in.readString();
        secondColor = in.readString();
        thirdColor = in.readString();

        game =  in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Team createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Team(in);
        }

        public Team[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Team[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Here's the Log cat:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.ids.a3090, PID: 20391
       java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:148)
       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
       at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:566)
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:422)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:406)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(Refle
```

Comment: post the code where u saving data

Comment: done please check now

Comment: check your References for GameType. Its causing problem for more information check here https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/66

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. `Team` references on `GameType`  which has this `Team`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't suppose that the circular reference will cause this problem