# Getting error during sonar scanner execution

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Getting the following error during sonar scanner execution. Not sure about this error.

```
14:35:23.003 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitBinaryExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:675)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:70)
14:35:23.014 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:35:23.014 DEBUG: Execution stop
```

What would the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: you tried to analyze  project with several modules having same key ??

Comment: You should provide much more information such as the SonarQube version you use, the plugins you have installed and a minimal project you are analyzing.

Comment: SonarQube 6.6 and Sonar Java 4.15