# C# with Selenium giving "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application which is working on .NET 4.6 platform.

As it is UI-Automation project, it needs to run continuously according to my requirement.

I am using `selenium-webdriver 3.8.0` and `Chromedriver 2.35.0`. It is running for 3 days and later it terminating by giving

> "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException".

My application gives exceptions(driver exceptions like "`NoSuchElementException`"), but I am handling them so its not stopping.

Is the driver cache filled? does that cause for this?
Please help me out.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Not really answerable this way. Post stack trace, how you handle that other error, anything else you can think of or that we ask. .

Comment: The `StackOverflowException`is mostly caused by unrestricted recursion. Your case is not so apparent, since it takes a long time, but even so, there is a possibility of small recursion, caused by handling of some events. Try review stack trace and search for recursion. Second cause of `StackOverflowException` is allocating big size of data on stack. This should not apply for C#, since there is no such a construct as in C: `int data[1024*1024];`, but perhaps a function with many variables might cause this error too, when the stack is already used to bigger extent. Try to post some code.

Comment: Thanks guys. its a big project, so i cant post small piece of code. In the terminal i am getting that error. and after that visualstudio stops debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: Do you see the stack trace in the terminal? Try to analyse it. When do you not see a stack trace, it will be hard. I'm not sure that the exception can be caught. Try add global unhandled exception handler and display/save the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok @Julo. thanks for that