# Error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" during recursion

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

**This is the code for implementation of Quicksort**

In this data structure quick sorting technique I have used algo as follows:

In ***partition method***

pivot the first element and i=1 and j=last index

comparing element at i and j with pivoted element as follows

1.while(a[i]<a[p])

increment i

2.while(a[j]>a[p])

decrement j

3.if i<j:

swap a[i] and a[j]

4.if i<j:

GO TO 1

else:

swap a[pivot] and a[j]

In ***Sorting Method***
after partition
let p(*return of partition method*) be position of pivoted element
p=call partition method
used ***recursion for sorting***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Q_Sort {
    int partition(int a[],int i,int j) {
        int n=a.length;
        int p=0;
        i=1;
        j=n-1;
        while(i<j){
            while(a[i]<a[p]) {
            i++;
            } 
            while(a[j]>a[p]) {
                --j;
            }
            if(i<j) {
                int t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[i];
                a[i]=t;
            }
        }
        int temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[p];
        a[p]=temp;
        
        return j;
    }
    void Sort(int a[], int low, int high)  
    {  
          
         
        if(low<high)  
        {  
            int p = partition(a, low, high);  
            Sort(a,low,p-1);  
            Sort(a,p+1,high);  
        }  
    }
    static void Display(int a[]) {
        int l=a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" "); 
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Q_Sort ob=new Q_Sort();
        System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
        n=s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            a[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Before Quick Sort" );
        Display(a);
        ob.Sort(a,0,n-1);
        System.out.println("After Quick Sort ");
        Display(a);
    }

}
```

[Error generated when running(*to see the pic click on link*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWQOT.png)

Comment: A likely duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror/47831474)

Comment: In more than 9 out of 10 questions asking this the problem turns out to be infinite recursion.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, because it is more than a decade since i used Java, but doesn’t a.length in partition(kr give you the length of the full array? If so, there is your problem. You don’t reduce your problem size in the recursion, so you recurse forever. You want to use the low to high interval. Set i to low and i to high-1 or something like that.

Comment: Actually, you already have them. Just don’t change i and j before the loop