# java.lang.StackOverflowError at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources

Tags: jsf, weblogic

I have a web project with Java 1.8, JSF, Spring MVC and Weblogic.

I am receiving this error while I navigate on my web project.

It has compiled without errors and published on Weblogic 12.2.1.4 without problems too.

This is the error log (is longer than this):

```
<BEA-101107> <[ServletContext@29440594[app:PROYECT_WEB module:PROYECTO_WEB path:null spec-version:3.1]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.oracle.classloader.SearchPolicy.recordParentDelegationStats(SearchPolicy.java:169)
    at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchSystemLoader.addResources(SearchSystemLoader.java:87)
    at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchSequence.addResources(SearchSequence.java:117)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$2.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:481)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$2.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:474)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.getResources(PolicyClassLoader.java:474)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getParentResources(GenericClassLoader.java:773)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:882)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getParentResources(GenericClassLoader.java:773)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:851)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getParentResources(GenericClassLoader.java:773)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:851)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getParentResources(GenericClassLoader.java:773)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:851)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getParentResources(GenericClassLoader.java:773)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:851)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.getResources(GenericClassLoader.java:738)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.getResources(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.FaceletWebappResourceHelper.findResource(FaceletWebappResourceHelper.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:539)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getResourceInfo(ResourceManager.java:319)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.viewExists(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1045)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.convertViewId(MultiViewHandler.java:576)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.derivePhysicalViewId(MultiViewHandler.java:596)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.deriveLogicalViewId(MultiViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:230)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
```

UPDATE: I have figured out that the problem is that Weblogic is not loading images

I have this:

```
<img  style="width:80px;" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/project/project.gif"  />
```

Comment: *"I have figured out that the problem is that Weblogic is not loading images"* this is just the consequence, not the cause.

Comment: First step is to analyze and clean up the runtime classpath of any duplicate classes conflicting each other. Common mistake of projects using Spring instead of standard JEE and then deploying to a full fledged JEE server such as WebLogic instead of a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat or Jetty, is that the runtime classpath of these projects are littered with JEE specific libraries/dependencies while these are *already* provided by the JEE server itself. In Maven terms, the dependency scope basically needs to be explicitly set to `provided` for them.

Comment: I still don´t know the cause but I know what is generating the problem.
I have an image on :

webapp / resources / images / image.jpg

    Well, weblogic is not capable to read the image from that but it works if I put it on :

webapp / images / image.jpg

Any idea why? Perhaps Weblogic bug?

Comment: @Homselan you have a different problem on wrblogic server caused by `StsckOverflowError`. Read more about it [how to resolve this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror).

Comment: RomanC: Nope. The stack trace shows that this StackOverflowError is not coming from user code, but it's coming from the server internal code. In other words, this specific error cannot be fixed by editing any user code as instructed in your duplicate link.

Comment: I coment the solution is this, but I don´t know why:

I have an image on : webapp / resources / images / image.jpg Well, weblogic is not capable to read the image from that. But it works if I put it on : webapp / images / image.jpg Any idea why? Perhaps Weblogic bug?

Comment: Exactly :) Possible Weblogic bug. Reminder: it's payware, so you can claim right on their support. Provided that your runtime classpath is clean and crisp, of course. See also my earlier comment. It would not be the first time I see a Spring project being littered with wrong dependencies when considering a normal Java EE server as target runtime instead of a custom stack such as Tomcat/Jetty.